# How to remove focus from a parent element when a child element is clicked

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I am new to styling. I have something like

```
<div className= 'parent'>
   <div className='foo'> <Increment> </div>
   <div className= 'child'>
        <input type = 'number'/>
   </div>
</div>
```

So for one of the styling scenario I am using .parent:focus-within{<>} in css. I want the parent class to not be focus when component  is clicked. Afaik , parent:focus-within will be true when any of its child is in focus.

Comment: Not sure what you are trying to do, when the child is clicked, you want to unfocus(blur) on the parent but are you expecting the child to be focused? Once you unfocus(blur) on the parent, then nothing in the parent will be focused. Or are you saying you don't want the focus event to trigger on the parent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can catch the focus event and use Event.stopPropagation() function.

Something like that:

```js
const handleFocus = (event) => {
event.stopPropagation()
}

<div className='parent'>
    <div className='foo'> <Increment/> </div>
    <div className= 'child' onFocus={handleFocus}>
        <input type = 'number'/>
    </div>
</div>
```